# FB.init called with one app, but I want to switch to another Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the main FB.init being called on all of my pages, but there are certain sections of the site where I'd like to get the user's permissions for a different app.

Is this possible? I don't think I can do another FB.init, but I'm wondering if I can specify a different app for a different task.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of why you'd want to do this; but can't you just store the [Facebook] access token for the two apps in your app's own session?